# Did Aida have her Inhuman powers inside the Framework?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

Aida’s Inhuman powers are attributed by Fitz and May to experiments on transferring Inhuman DNA done within the Framework, suggesting that the transfer was done there:

> COULSON: No, no, no! She has Inhuman powers now? Can we get a break,
> please? Can we get one break?
>
> MAY: Guess they weren’t assessing powers at Hydra as much as
> collecting them.
>
> <sub>*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, “The Return”</sub>

Her body was said to have been transferred from the Framework to real flesh, which would also tend to suggest that **the powers were transferred to her there**: if the Darkhold could (or would) do it, there wouldn’t have been any need for the experiments there.

It might seem that Aida didn’t have her powers within the Framework, since she didn’t heal from the injuries she suffered. However, her healing ability is strongly implied to be because she’s made of the same substance as the Darkhold: according to the Superior, Robby Reyes could harm her because the Ghost Rider came from the same dimension as the Darkhold and her body. As such, she wouldn’t have had it even had the Inhuman powers been transferred over.

**Is there any evidence that Aida had her Inhuman powers in the Framework?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer, no.

She never shows any Inhuman abilities in the Framework, even when it would've helped her a lot or saved her

> like when she were falling from the Triskelion after Daisy kicked her butt

Also, the Framework replicates reality at a point where Inhuman powers works exactly like in the real MCU, so she would've needed the Inhuman gene to be able to get ONE power.
More importantly, this is never addressed in the show, so no, she didn't have any Inhuman powers in the Framework.

My understanding is that they were collecting Inhuman powers (or data on them, more likely) to replicate them on Aida's human body through Project Looking Glass. It's safe to say that the Darkhold allows its reader to perform genetic manipulations on an artificially created human body, even if it means introducing the Inhuman gene and multiple selected powers.

So Aida added Inhuman powers (that she analysed into the Framework) to her human body.

Comment: I was going to add the same answer, but you covered it here. Basically, she used the knowledge gained inside the Framework to design her flesh-and-blood body to have the Inhuman abilities.